# Set query string value of iframe in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, query-string

Iam having Two Page Parent.aspx and Child.Aspx, in Parent.aspx i have used iframe to cal Child.aspx. But when i load Parent my Child Page Load is getting called, which i need it based on Condition, 
So for that i have used Querystring for the SRC of iframe.

I just wanted to check the query string name and call the Child.aspx page / Page Load of Child.

How can i check that Condition?

```
 <div id="Omit" class="Omit" style="display:none">
      <iframe src="Omission.aspx?name=omission" id="Omission" class="iframe" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Want to set the name of Query string, like this

```
  var name = Request.QueryString("omission");
```

But still when i load my Parent Page, Child Page Load is getting called. Where i must bind some avlues based on Input from Parent.

How can i do this in my condition.
Any help is thankful.

Comment: Means before sending query string value you need to first check in parent page that what value your query string has...

Comment: @Rahul Not like that.., i just want to stop Page load of iframe src page when i run my parent page., so need to check Querystring of parent value and allow to run page load of child (iframe)

Comment: means you want to call child page "page_load" method from parent page on some special value like if your query string has "abc" then call childpage else notcallchildpage..is it

Comment: @Rahul Exactly sir..., Yes I want to check that condition and then Load page.., because here my child must carry values from Parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to set the query string value from codebehind like declare a static global variable above the page load like

```
Static String fileMgrQstring  = ""
```

Now on page load assign value to your **fileMgrQstring**  variable like

```
String Name = "omission";
//Check here condition
if(Name == "omission")
{
fileMgrQstring = "Omission.aspx?name=" + Name;
}
else
{
// Do whatever you want....
}
```

and in Html page assign **fileMgrQstring** variable to your iframe like

```
<div id="Omit" class="OmitPorts" style="display:none">
      <iframe src="<%= fileMgrQstring %>" id="PortOmission" class="iframe" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>
    </div>
```

For reading query string value you have to use

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
```

i have the same problem what i use this type of logic and now it works fine for me.

Hope you understand and it works for you.

Comment: I need to check fileMgrQstring  condtion in my Parent Page Load rite

Comment: yes i declare and assign value to this variable on your parent page..that's why u can easily check condition here.

Comment: Still its going to Child Page Load?

Comment: yes it will go to child page if Name variable = omission then it will go to child page and if Name variable is not = omission then it will not go..try to understand my logic,,it's simple.use debugger also.

Comment: I am trying to use this in my Javascript the code of Page_Load as iam using my total code in Jquery..., when i alert fileMgrQstring its giving PortOmission?name=omission but still My tagrent page is Not getting Viewed., Its Blank

Comment: you need to use page extension as well like 
PortOmission.aspx?name=omission

Comment: and also mentioned that what you are trying please put your new code as per i mentioned in your question as well

Comment: But My trial is not still working..., I am trying to use it Jquery It is either Going to Page_Load or Not getting called

Comment: if it's going to page load then use debugger and check that which condition it is using if or else.